# How to replace blocking behind shower valve?

Tags: shower, valve, studs, nails

To fix a shower leak we cut out the drywall and the blocking behind the shower valve so as not to disturb the tiles inside the shower. After replacing the shower valve, we're left with some nails and a part of the block sticking out on either side of the studs. The nails that held the block are very tough and hard to remove. What is the recommended way to replace it?

When we were trying to hammer the nails out, their heads were stuck In between the double studs. Then we tried to bend the nails, one snapped in half, the other was still on. Oscillating saw didn’t make a dent on it.

[image: missing cross stud]

Comment: Since your oscillating saw didn't cut the nails, I'd suggest you were using the wrong kind of blade. Wood cutting blades have a low tooth per inch count with deep gullets for clearing the saw dust. Metal cutting blades have very high tooth per inch count with very small gullets. If you use a metal cutting blade, odds are good you'll cut right through the nails. I've cut _loads_ of framing nails over the last several years with proper metal cutting blades. I've hit a few nails with wood cutting blades and the nail will destroy the teeth in seconds.

Comment: Lots of people provided good answers on how to remove the small section of stud, but you could also just use a mending plate to attach a shorter section of 2x4 blocking to the remaining blocking, then screw into the adjacent stud. Its not structural so doesn't need to be that strong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a chisel or drill to split the short block stub along the wood grain. It'll practically fall off the nails. I wouldn't think it would be that difficult to simply pry the block off the stud, though. Nails in end grain don't hold particularly well.

Then grab the nails with a Vice-Grip plier or similar and bend them back and forth at the face of the stud. They'll snap off after a few cycles.

Install a new block with screws run it at angles from above and below. It would help prevent splitting and make things easier to pre-drill through the block. I'd press the block gently against the valve bracket, and consider using a few gobs of silicone or some strong double-sided foam tape for attachment.

You can reuse the drywall as a patch if you didn't break it up too badly. Just float some backing at a few locations (top and near the junction box), then screw it back in place. The tape joints will lock it all together. For future projects, cut a bigger opening *around* the junction box so your repair joints don't fall on it. You're going to be skimming well past it to get a flat finish.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably add two new cross pieces and use screws, above and below the cut one.

This will also give you backing to repair the drywall.

Drill a couple holes in the new cross pieces and use zip ties to hold the pipes on(this will probably be the most difficult part).

The tiles probably will not like you hammering nails in.

Comment: Step zero - cut a bigger hole in the drywall to remove the cut stub. Angle brackets can be very useful for the screw connections.

Comment: The original block aligned with the valve. I'd want the replacement there as well.